# Hi I am currently taking an IBM course and my enable continuous delivery button is not working. What do I do?

Tags: ibm-cloud, continuous-delivery

Create the back-end of a visitors tracking app.
IBM course.
Continuous delivery button not working.

Comment: This does not look like a programming issue, but something with the course or environment.

Answer (score 0):

please reach out to the Dev Team on our public Slack wks.
Register here: https://ic-devops-slack-invite.us-south.devops.cloud.ibm.com/
Then post your question here: https://ibm-devops-services.slack.com/archives/CH7DU7BL0/p1553589948001400

Thanks